# Is there any advantages of using rpm-based distro for Java development?

Tags: package-management, rpm, java

I'm using Arch Linux now and everything seems okay. But I'd like to try using some rpm-based linux distro like *Fedora* or *OpenSUSE*. It seems that most Java server machines use Red Hat, which is rpm-based.

What is advantages of using *Red Hat* for *Java server*? And is there any advantages of using it for Java development on my laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that most Java server machines use Red Hat

That may be true (I don't know), although it's probably reasons other than this provides some particular advantage with regard to java.  Redhat is a popular production server because (for a fee) it comes with commercial support from Redhat.  This relieves people of having to pay their own support staff, contractors, etc.

Java is intended to be portable and to the extent that POSIX style system possesses pecularities, they hold them in common and all GNU/Linux systems are the same in that sense.  They also all use more or less the same kernel, so there is not some special integration going on there.